# Mysql: if condition not gives unexpected value for float value

Tags: mysql, if-statement

My mysql query is like this

```
select if(brand_name="royal", b.multiplier, 1) as multiplier from brand;
```

my database have below record

```
brand_name = royal,
multiplier = 1.06 (type: float(5,2))
```

in result multiplier value should be **1.06** but it give value in result as : **1.0599999427795**

Please can you tell me how I can resolve this issue ?

Comment: Isn't that how floats work? If you want a decimal, use a decimal !?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the way floats behave:

[image: Decimal 1.06 represented as single]

The correct solution is to use [`DECIMAL(M, D)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) datatype.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fix the decimal point value, need to change `type` of multiplier from `float` -> `decimal`

[image]

Then use this code

```
SELECT IF( brand_name =  "apple", multiplier, 1 ) AS multiplier
FROM stack
LIMIT 0 , 30
```